# cURL works in CLI but not on HTTP: Could not resolve host

Tags: php, curl, dns

I'm having an issue with cURL where any request returns `Could not resolve host: example.com; Name or service not known` when the script is accessed from a browser.

However if I run the very same script from the cli I get the expected response.

Here is a snippit of the script I was using to test:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://example.com');

$options = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Accept: */*')
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

try {
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    print_r($e);
}

if($output === false){
    echo curl_error($curl); //returns "Could not resolve host: example.com; Name or service not known" when accessed from browser
}
else {
    print_r($output); //returns expected response when called from cli
}
curl_close($curl);
```

This problem started somewhat recently, and is hosted on a managed VM. I contacted support for the host, but they did not have much insight. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue recently on one of our live CentOS boxes on a VM stack.

In our case the issue was caused by a recent OS update to the OpenSSL and glibc shared libraries used by cURL.  Restarting the Apache/nginx/PHP-FPM services resolved the issue for us.